# Sys Admin migrating vm to azure

Tags: linux, database, azure, migration, system-administration

I just want to ask what's the best way to migrate a .ova file to azure. I have read many ways but i want to know which one is the most efficient. The os is oracle linux and I want to deploy an Oracle db on it. Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The best and standard way is:

1. Create Azure VM with the correct specifications to support your Oracle database.
2. Migrate your Oracle database to the Azure VM.

In order to migrate your existing Oracle Database to Azure VM, you need to choose a VM image which suits best for your business requirements.

You can find the list of Oracle VM images and their deployment on Microsoft Azure [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/workloads/oracle/oracle-vm-solutions).

For migration guidance, design consideration,  licensing, backup, etc. recommendations, you can visit [Oracle database migration to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/solution-ideas/articles/reference-architecture-for-oracle-database-migration-to-azure).